# How can I treat a canvas context resource created at runtime as a dependency in a require.js plugin?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webgl

I'm trying to create a require.js plugin to load GLSL Shader files, construct a Shader Program, and return it to the module that is using the files as dependencies.  However, I'm wondering if I'm asking my plugin to do something that is both possible and wise in terms of things it should be concerned about.

Right now, I have written the module following the guidelines on require.js' plugin page taking a cue from the `text` and `i18n` plugins.  Those modules have slightly different goals in terms of what they need to accomplish though.  `text` returns file text, which was simple enough to get going.  `i18n` returns an object of localized strings depending on a locale.  Again, somewhat in line with what I want.  However, neither one of those care about what the DOM is doing whenever they run.

In order to get my module working, I need a handle to a `<canvas>` element or a WebGL context created from that canvas.  For brevity, lets consider the context `gl`.

Once I have loaded up the shader source files, I need to use functions within `gl` to put them into the context, compile them, link them, and produce a program to keep track of.  If I have `gl`, there is no issue.  Looking at some of the templating plugins for require.js, I see that they sometimes just create a temporary DOM element, do what they need to do, and return whatever they manufactured using the element.

This would almost solve my problem except that I don't believe context resources can be shared between one another.  That is to say, if I added a `<canvas>` from within the plugin, got the context, and created the shader, I wouldn't be able to utilize that Shader Program from within the context that I **actually** want to use it in.

Is there a way to have require.js provide the `gl` to my plugin in a convenient way perhaps through the dependencies?  If not, am I asking too much of my plugin and instead should focus on only loading shader source within it and delegating the actual Program construction to another module?

### glsl.js

```
(function() {

    // Parser to grab the shaders to use
    function parse(name) {
        var components = {
            vert : name.match(/v\:(.+)\!/)[1],
            frag : name.match(/f\:(.+)/)[1],
        };
        return components;
    }

    // fetchText helper from requirejs/text
    function fetchText(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(evt) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }

    // Construct a Shader Program from components
    function Program(gl, vert, frag) {
        /*
         * Problem is that I don't know how to effectively get "gl" defined here
         */

        // Check for validity
        function checkShader(shader) {
            if (gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                console.log("All good");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error compiling shader: %s", gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            }
        }

        var vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        var fShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        gl.shaderSource(vShader, vert);
        gl.shaderSource(fShader, frag);

        gl.compileShader(vShader);
        gl.compileShader(fShader);

        checkShader(vShader);
        checkShader(fShader);
    }
    //

    // Define our GLSL module
    define({
        // Make files module relative
        normalize : function(name, normalize) {
            // Get componenets
            var parsed = parse(name);

            // Normalize
            parsed.vert = normalize(parsed.vert);
            parsed.frag = normalize(parsed.frag);

            // Return normalized value
            return "v:" + parsed.vert + "!f:" + parsed.frag;
        },

        // Do the loading of the Shader
        load : function(name, req, onload, config) {

            // Predefine variables
            var components = null, vertPromise = null, fragPromise = null;

            // Parse the components
            components = parse(name),

            // Make Vertex Promise
            vertPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                fetchText(req.toUrl(components.vert + ".vert"), function(text) {
                    resolve(text);
                });
            }),

            // Make Fragment Promise
            fragPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                fetchText(req.toUrl(components.frag + ".frag"), function(text) {
                    resolve(text);
                });
            });

            // Wait for XHR to resolve
            Promise.all([
                    vertPromise,
                    fragPromise
            ]).then(function(values) {
                // Done loading them

                // Construct a new shader program from values
                var shaderProgram = new Program(gl, values[0], values[1]);

                // Deliver the shader program
                onload(shaderProgram);
            });
        }
    });
}());
```

### app.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : "js",
    paths : {
        domReady : "lib/domReady/domReady",
        glsl : "module/glsl/glsl"
    }
});

require([
        "domReady",
        "glsl!v:../res/shader!f:../res/shader"
], function(domReady, fragShader) {
    domReady(function() {
        // Predefine Variables
        var c = null, gl = null;

        // Get reference to our canvas
        c = document.getElementById("testCanvas");

        // Get an OpenGL Context
        gl = c.getContext("experimental-webgl");

        /*
         * I should have a constructed and compiled shader here referenced by
         * fragShader
         */

        // Doesn't work yet
        gl.useProgram(fragShader);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting the canvas / webgl context in its own module

```
// gl.js
define(function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  return gl;
});
```

Now make every other module that needs webgl use that module

```
define(['./gl'], function(gl) {
  // access the webgl context with
  gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);
  // access the canvas
  gl.canvas.width = 150;
});
```

[Here's an example](http://greggman.com/downloads/examples/require-gl/index.html). You can see the `gl.js` is included only once even though it is referenced by 6 different files.

Comment: Unless it were the same canvas/context as the one that I am hoping to target, I would be unable to use a resource generated in another context in the target context.  If I understand the dependency mechanism, it would effectively create a new canvas/context every time I use `./gl` as a dependency which would create the resource and then kill it after the module has run.  Is there a way to keep that one singular created canvas going throughout the "run" of the app?

Comment: No, it will always be the same canvas. Each file is only included and executed once. As far as your target either have the `gl.js` module look up the canvas in your HTML or else insert it into your DOM wherever you want it. It will work just fine. [see example](http://greggman.com/downloads/examples/require-gl/index.html). requirejs works loading each file once & calling `define`. That passes back an array of dependencies and a func. It looks at the dependencies to load more files. Only after it's loaded all the files (once each) it then calls the functions (once each) in the correct order.